# Change the text of a focused JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

in the following example:

```
JTextField name = new JTextField("Enter Name");
JTextField place = new JTextField("Enter Place of birth");
JTextField a = new JTextField("Enter a");
JTextField b = new JTextField("Enter b");
JTextField c = new JTextField("Enter c");


FocusListener f = new FocusListener() {
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

  }

  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

  }

name.addfocuslistener(f);
place.addfocuslistener(f);
a.addfocuslistener(f);
b.addfocuslistener(f);
c.addfocuslistener(f);
```

How can i set the text of the JTextfield to an empty string when focus is gained?

So something like:

```
focusedTextField.settext("");
```

Comment: `How can i set the text of the JTextfield to an empty string when focus is gained?` - you make an assumption that the user will always enter text when the text field gains focus. What if the user tabs from field to field? You will lose the original text and then all the text field will contain nothing so the user will have no idea what the text field is for. You really need the ability to redisplay the prompt when the user hasn't entered any text into the text field and focus is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at the [JavaDocs for `FocusEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html), it has a numbe of interesting properties, including `getSource`, which all `EventObject`s have and `getComponent` which returns *"Returns the originator of the event."* as a `Component`, which is very useful.

Using this knowledge, you could do something like...

```
FocusListener f = new FocusListener() {
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
      Component source = e.getComponent();
      if (source instanceof JTextField) {
          ((JTextField)source).setText("");
      }
  }
```

You should also have a look at [How to Write a Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

> How can i set the text of the JTextfield to an empty string when focus is gained?

I'm guessing you don't really want to set the text field to an empty string when it gains focus. The user could tab off the field without entering any text so you would lose the prompt forever.

Take a look at [Text Field Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for a reusable class that will allow you to show prompt text in the text field.

The class has a few different options so you can control when the prompt is displayed.

You can even give the text different attributes so it looks more like a prompt rather than actual text.

Answer (score 0):

In the `focusGained()` method you are passed a [FocusEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html) which should contain the object that initiated the event using `e.getSource()`. If cast to the type we expect the source to be, a `JTextField`, then to clear text we simply do:

```
 public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
          ((JTextField)e.getSource()).setText("");
  }
```

I haven't tested this, but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to derive the swing element which was the target of FocusEvent and cast it to a JTextField.

Inside your focusGained method you can use:

```
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    JTextField target = (JTextField)e.getSource();
    target.setText("TEXT_TO_SET");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set this in focusGained merhod
JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
If(!tf.isFocusOwner()) tf.setText("");